# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear una aplicación únicamente para iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, itunes

Quiero enviar mi app a revisión y me esta pidiendo que ingrese capturas de pantalla de distintos dispositivos.

El problema que tengo es que mi app no es para iPad... y la opción de iPad no es opcional.

¿Donde puedo indicar que la app es solo para iPhone?.
Muchas gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede. Tiene que funcionar en iPads también. Va en función del sistema operativo, por tanto, tienes que dar soporte para iOS.

Comment: Como explicarias que algunas aplicaciones tienen solo para Iphone i no para Ipad? @Jon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lo debes indicar en las opciones de tu proyecto de xcode, y también en el info, si lo subes sin el info los de apple hacen pruebas en ocaciones dede ipads y te dicen que no se ve bien, a si que es importante el device capabilities desde el info.

Otro punto importante es, el Capabilities del Info lo puedes cambiar siempre y cuando no hayas liberado la app, si ya liberaste no lo podrás cambiar y subir por que los apple te dicen que no puedes restringir una liberación si la anterior abarcaba mas dispositivos.

Aquí esta la configuración del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Aqui esta el Required devices Capabilities, en esta opción tiene el armv7 y ese valor se lo cambiar por telephony

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ver las diferentes opciones te anexo el link de apple.

[Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Una ves teniendo bien la configuración debería de quitarte la opción de ipads del itunes connect, obviamente tienes que subir el compilado a itunes y seleccionarlo para liberar o probar.

Comment: Voy a probarlo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Cuando creas el proyecto le puedes indicar para qué dispositivo quieres hacerlo.

Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También podrás modificarlo en las propiedades del proyecto.

Answer (score 4):

Añadiendo a la respuesta de Shadros, puedes cambiarlo una vez ya hayas creado el proyecto en las propiedades de tu app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pulsa en tu proyecto, y en la pestaña de 'General' encontrarás una sección de Deployment Info.

Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo esa configuración bien. Lo que vi es que en el info.plist tenía esto: Supported interface orientations (iPad) .. nose si puede tener que ver.